# informatica elsatic cluster node image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, informatica, aws-auto-scaling, iics-di

I want to create elastic cluster(CDI) in informatica GUI.

I had given all configuration, when I do validate I got following error

> **1. Cannot find the cluster node image at path [309956199498/RHEL_HA-7.9_HVM-20210315-x86_64-2-Hourly2-GP2]**

> **2. Check AWS IAM Policy [arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/master_role] because the action [autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingInstances] to resource [arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:xxx:autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName/*] is not allowed. There are no matching policy action statements.**

How to solve this?

Comment: Is it related to informatica tool?

Comment: @KoushikRoy Yes

Comment: @KoushikRoy I too am facing the same problem when trying to create a Elastic Cluster from IICS. I have followed the steps from the doc https://onlinehelp.informatica.com/IICS/prod/admin/en/index.htm#page/oo-iics-administrator_cdie/Create_IAM_roles.html and also tried creating the policies using the generate-policies-for-userdefined-roles.sh. script, but till now no luck.